# Ionic 5 | Detect app closing or going to background

Tags: ionic-framework, background, exit, ionic5

I Cannot detect when the app is closing or going to background on ionic 5. Pause event is not working. What i tried is this:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.pause = this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
       this.experimentService.stop().then(res => {
         //I do something that doing things to a raspberry pi (don't know if that matters), that take some time to respond
       });
     });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.pause.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding async as per the documentation?  https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform

Comment: Yes! You are the best <3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @E. Maggini comment, the problem was that I did not use async.

Solution:

```
this.platform.pause.subscribe(async () => {
       this.experimentService.stop().then(res => {
         
       });
     });
```